# PostgreSQL lots of Tables

Tags: database, postgresql

we am at a point where I have more than a thousand Tables in our PostgreSQL database server. I remember reading that there was a way to speed up the database once it reached more than a thousand Tables, but I cannot seem to find any mention of this on the Web with Google. Any help would be nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall anything specific to a table count that is greater than 1000, but you may have been thinking of using tablespaces to spread db objects/tables over different volumes to enhance performance? (i.e. tables that more write heavy on a different volume to tables that are read heavy, or splitting different sets of heavy use tables over volumes on different channels)

[tablespaces are covered here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) in the postgres docs.

having said this, unless there are specific performance issues you need to address, I wouldn't make the changes arbitrarily...

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL creates a [file in the filesystem for every table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/storage-file-layout.html); depending on your underlying filesystem, you'll eventually run into performance problems when any process (PostgreSQL included) reads the directory metadata. To alleviate this, you'll want to create a number of different tablespaces and place different tables in different tablespaces in order to prevent having thousands of files in the same directory.

It might help to read a bit about the [CREATE TABLESPACE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-createtablespace.html) and [ALTER TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/sql-altertable.html) commands to move tables into a given tablespace.

Answer (score 0):

You may be referring specifically to the advice around tuning max_fsm_relations when you have lots of tables. But that requirement was removed in 8.4, and it's now automatically tuned for you.